# R: Hyper-parameter Tuning for XGBoost on a Multi-class Target Variable using Bayesian Optimization

Tags: r, performance, hyperparameters

I have seen this being implemented in Python, however, I am looking into using Bayesian Optimization for XGBoost model hyper-parameter tuning in R. There are other optimization implementations for multi-class target variables, and there are resources for the Bayesian implementation only for binary target variables. However, I have not been able to find what I am looking for.

Here is the simple implementation of the XGBoost model for the `iris` dataset:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("datasets")
library("xgboost")

data(iris)
summary(iris)


# Convert the Species to an integer class starting at 0
species = as.factor(iris$Species)
label = as.integer(as.factor(iris$Species))-1
iris$Species = NULL

# Split data into train and test
n = nrow(iris)
train.index = sample(n,floor(0.7*n))
train.data = as.matrix(iris[train.index,])
train.label = label[train.index]
test.data = as.matrix(iris[-train.index,])
test.label = label[-train.index]

# Transform the two data sets into xgb.Matrix
xgb.train = xgb.DMatrix(data=train.data,label=train.label)
xgb.test = xgb.DMatrix(data=test.data,label=test.label)

# Define the parameters for multinomial classification
num_class = length(levels(species))
params = list(
  booster="gbtree",
  eta=0.001,
  max_depth=5,
  gamma=3,
  subsample=0.75,
  colsample_bytree=1,
  objective="multi:softprob",
  eval_metric="mlogloss",
  num_class=num_class
)

# Train the XGBoost classifer
xgb.fit=xgb.train(
  params=params,
  data=xgb.train,
  nrounds=10000,
  nthreads=1,
  early_stopping_rounds=10,
  watchlist=list(val1=xgb.train,val2=xgb.test),
  verbose=0
)

# Review the final model and results
xgb.fit

# Predict outcomes with the test data
xgb.pred = predict(xgb.fit,test.data,reshape=T)
xgb.pred = as.data.frame(xgb.pred)
colnames(xgb.pred) = levels(species)

# Use the predicted label with the highest probability
xgb.pred$prediction = apply(xgb.pred,1,function(x) colnames(xgb.pred)[which.max(x)])
xgb.pred$label = levels(species)[test.label+1]

# Calculate the final accuracy
result = sum(xgb.pred$prediction==xgb.pred$label)/nrow(xgb.pred)
print(paste("Final Accuracy =",sprintf("%1.2f%%", 100*result)))
```

Now, the idea for me is to use Bayesian Optimization for hyperparameter tuning.